# How did Regulus Black discover the Dark Lord's secret?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

We all know that Regulus Black was the first person to discover the Dark Lord's secret and also managed to locate one of the Horcrux.
The question is,

- How did he learn about the Horcruxes that the Dark Lord created?
- How did he manage to find one?
- How did he happen to get a replica of the Horcrux?

Comment: The first one seems like it's answered here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/how-did-r-a-b-get-to-know-about-voldemorts-horcruxes?rq=1